# How to prevent flow errors from being sent to my email address?

Tags: email, process-builder, user, deactivate

I did some consulting for a company a couple of years ago, and I set up some processes in Process Builder. Now it seems that they hired another consultant to customize other things, but sometimes I get error messages from some flows I set up.

I've told them to deactivate my user, obviously, and also to change my user's email address. But I am receiving the errors now, even after those two steps.

Is there anything else I can do to stop those messages from showing up in my inbox? Gmail doesn't seem to be able to pick the Org ID form the email messages. That would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The below features comes out from this idea:- [Choose Who To Send Flow Fault emails and Process Builder Error Emails to](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DvMGAA0)

**Control Who Receives Flow and Process Error Emails**

When a process or flow interview fails, Salesforce sends a detailed flow error email to the admin who last modified the process or flow. But perhaps that admin isn’t the best person to read and act on the details of what was executed and what went wrong. Now you can send flow error emails to the Apex exception email recipients that you specify in Setup.

**Where:** This change applies to Lightning Experience and Salesforce Classic in Enterprise, Performance, Unlimited, and Developer editions.

**How:** To change where flow error emails are sent, go to the Process Automation Settings page in Setup. Then update the Send Process or Flow Error Email To field.

To specify users and email addresses as Apex exception email recipients, go to the Apex Exception Email page in Setup. Keep in mind that these users and email addresses also receive Apex exception emails.

Reference:- [Control Who Receives Flow and Process Error Emails](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer18/release-notes/rn_forcecom_flow_email_apex.htm)